# How to allow specific parameter values in OpenAPI specification (Swagger UI) using FastAPI?

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm reading the tutorial on [Path Parameter Validation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/).

I want to allow the strings "a" "b" and "c" as possible parameter values. I want these values to show up in the OpenAPI documentation (i.e., [FastAPI's automatic docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/features/#automatic-docs)), so that the API user does not have to guess them. How can I make these values show up in the documentation?

Here is my implementation:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException

app = FastAPI()

parameters = ["a", "b", "c"]

@app.get("/endpoint/{parameter}")
def endpoint(parameter: str):
    if parameter not in parameters:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="parameter must be a, b, or c")
    return {"parameter": parameter}
```

Comment: Does using an Enum satisfy your documentation need? https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#enums-and-choices It's also shown in the tutorial page you linked: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/#create-an-enum-class

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure what you mean by within then OpenAPI. Generally, this is done with the docstrings if you want it front and center. Also, have you looked at this? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/metadata/

Comment: By within the OpenAPI I mean the documentation available at http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs . Enum satisfies my documentation need. Thank you MatsLindh!

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

You could use [`enums`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#enums-and-choices), by creating an [`Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Enum) sub-class, as described in [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/#create-an-enum-class):

```py
from enum import Enum

class MyParam(str, Enum):
    a= "a"
    b= "b"
    c= "c"

@app.get("/{my_param}")
def index(my_param: MyParam):
    return {"my_param": my_param}
```

### Option 2

Alternatively, you could use [`Literal`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#literal-type) type, which allows you to specify that a parameter may accept only specific `Literal` values:

```py
from typing import Literal

@app.get("/{my_param}")
def index(my_param: Literal["a", "b", "c"]):
    return {"my_param": my_param}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use an `Enum` for parameter validation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/#create-an-enum-class) and the allowed values will appear in the documentation site.

```py
from enum import Enum

from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException

app = FastAPI()

class AllowedParameterValues(str, Enum):
    a = "a"
    b = "b"
    c = "c"


@app.get("/endpoint/{parameter}")
def endpoint(parameter: AllowedParameterValues):
    return {"parameter": parameter}
```