# fastapi multiple select in open api parameter

Tags: fastapi, openapi

Is it possible to add multiple select for a dropdown in fastapi openapi?
I only manage to select one.

- if I set `Optional[List]` it wont run, the enum?).
- if I set `{[ids]}`in the routes openapi says it is a array and no dropdown.

```
@app.get("/schedules")
@app.get("/schedules/{ids}", include_in_schema=False)
@app.get("/schedules/{ids}/{active}")
async def GetScedules(
  ids:Optional[str]=Query(None, enum=[str(id) for id in appconfig['projectids']]),
  active:Optional[str]=Query(None, enum=["active", "notactive"])):
  """ list gitlab schedules sorted on projectids """
  if isinstance(ids, str): # convert str to list
    if ',' in ids:
      ids = ids.split(',')
    else:
      ids = [ids]
```

[image: I can only choose one, but like to choose multiple]

Comment: The param needs to be an array of enum, something like `Optional[List[YourEnum]]`.

Comment: You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74370808/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73401333/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76131490/17865804) helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use Pydantic dataclass as shown bellow. You can find more information in this [fastapi issue link](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/5042)

```
from typing import Optional, List
from enum import Enum

from fastapi import FastAPI, Query, Depends
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

app = FastAPI()

appconfig = {"projectsids": ["1", "2", "3"]}
enum = Enum("enum", {str(i):i for i in appconfig['projectsids']})

@dataclass
class ScheduleModel:
    ids_in: Optional[List[enum]] = Query(None)

@app.get("/schedules")
    async def GetSchedules(
    ids: ScheduleModel=Depends(),
    activate: Optional[str]=Query(None, enum=["activate", "notactive"])
):

    if isinstance(ids, ScheduleModel):
        if ids.ids_in and "," in ids.ids_in:
            ids = ids.split(",")
        else:
            ids = [ids]
    
        return {"ids": ids, "active": activate}
```

Comment: I just found that the resulting swagger interface for a multiple `<select>` option will trigger a `422 Error: Unprocessable Entity` due to the format of the POST.  The curl command presents multiple selections as comma-separated `param=one,two` rather than `param=one&param=two` (which will work as expected).